# Запустить генерацию один раз для нескольких тестов NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, юнит-тесты, nunit

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-то объединить тесты, что бы несколько тестов запускали 1 метод и дожидались его выполнения.
Суть такая: Есть огромная генерация, которая занимает приблизительно час времени. Нужно, что бы несколько тестов делали для себя пресетап и потом запускали генерацию и ждали её завершения, после чего продолжали свои проверки. Генерация не должна запускаться несколько раз, это очень затратно по времени и тесты тоже нельзя объединить в один

Comment: Ну, наверное, классическое решение: некий метод `GetData`, который вызывают тесты. Внутри этого метода - `lock`.

Comment: Не могли бы вы немного подробнее объяснить подход? В итоге я получу 1 тест GetData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим, имеется некий класс, который нужно протестировать, с двумя методами:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar(List<int> list)
    {
        return list.Min();
    }

    public int Baz(List<int> list)
    {
        return list.Max();
    }
}
```

Тесты для него:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FooTests
{
    private readonly object _locker = new object();
    private List<int> _list;

    private List<int> GetData()
    {
        if (_list == null)
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                if (_list == null)
                {
                    Console.Beep();
                    _list = new List<int>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        _list.Add(i);
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return _list;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Foo_Bar_ReturnsCorrectResult()
    {
        // Arrange
        var list = GetData();

        var sut = new Foo();

        // Act
        var result = sut.Bar(list);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Foo_Baz_ReturnsCorrectResult()
    {
        // Arrange
        var list = GetData();

        var sut = new Foo();

        // Act
        var result = sut.Baz(list);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(99, result);
    }
}
```

Два тестовых метода используют один и тот же набор данных (`List<int>`), который долго генерируется (добавлен `Thread.Sleep`). Эти данные хранятся в поле тестового класса. Метод, первым вызвавший генерацию, будет ждать её завершения. Если тестовый фреймворк допускает параллельное выполнение тестов, то другие паралльно запущенные тестовые методы будут ждать своей очереди на блокировке.

Я использовал стандартный double lock. Можно и другие способы применить.
`Console.Beep()` поставлен просто для того, чтобы на слух определить, сколько раз он вызывается. Так-то он не нужен.

Comment: Понял Вас. Спасибо большое, буду пробовать у себя

Comment: А почему не используете атрибут `[TestFixtureSetUp]` ?

Comment: @Bulson - отчасти, это дело вкуса. А кроме того, это сразу даёт понять, откуда берутся данные. Смотрим код тестового метода - в нём видно вызов `GetData`. При использовании метода c `SetUp` где-то что-то генерируется... но это не очевидно при взгляде на тестовый метод.

Comment: @Bulson - [Prefer helper methods to setup and teardown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#prefer-helper-methods-to-setup-and-teardown). Также в известной книге The Art of Unit Testing рекомендуется использовать helper methods.